# "no method found for type T in the current scope" when wrapping a type

Tags: rust, adapter

I am trying to make adapters around 2 different types that do the same job and I cannot rewrite the two types.

`X` has a method which consumes `self` so a run-time polymorphic wrapper is not applicable. The only option is a static generic approach.

```
struct X {}

impl X {
    fn f(self, n: i32) {
        println!("n = {}", n);
    }
    fn new() -> X {
        X {}
    }
}

struct AdapterX {
    x: X
}

impl AdapterX {
    fn uf(self, n: i32) {
        self.x.f(n)
    }
    fn new(x: X) -> AdapterX {
        AdapterX { x: x }
    }
}

fn useAdapted<T>(a: T) {
    a.uf(10)
}

fn main() {
    let x = X::new();
    useAdapted::<AdapterX>(AdapterX::new(x));
}
```

The compiler fails with:

```
error: no method named `uf` found for type `T` in the current scope
    a.uf(10)
      ^~
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
fn useAdapted<T>(a: T) {
    a.uf(10)
}
```

This says

> give me **any possible** type, and I will call the `uf` method on it

That's clearly nonsense, as you could pass in a `String` or `bool` or `HashMap` or a `File` or a .... (you get the point).

There's no method `uf` that applies to **every** type, so the compiler tells you so. As you discovered, you have to provide a *bound* on the generic type with one or more *traits*. Methods and associated functions from those traits will be usable inside the method.

Also note that the Rust style is `snake_case`; the function should be called `use_adapted`.

Comment: how do you set this bound?

Comment: @mjwrazor if you scroll down a bit, you'll see that [OP introduces a trait and uses it as a bound](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38813039/155423).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure it out; the wrapper struct is not needed. The right way is a generic trait. I also missed the type scope for the generic type variable.

```
struct X {}

impl X {
    fn f(self, n: i32) {
        println!("n = {}", n);
    }
    fn new() -> X {
        X {}
    }
}

trait Adapter<T> {
    fn uf(self, n: i32);
}

impl Adapter<X> for X {
    fn uf(self, n: i32) {
        self.f(n)
    }
}

struct Y {}

impl Y {
    fn g(self, n: f32) {
        println!("m = {}", n);
    }
    fn new() -> Y {
        Y {}
    }
}

impl Adapter<Y> for Y {
    fn uf(self, n: i32) {
        self.g(n as f32)
    }
}

fn use_adapted<A, T: Adapter<A>>(a: T) {
    a.uf(10)
}

fn main() {
    use_adapted(X::new());
    use_adapted(Y::new());
}
```